# splitting and merging Ranges array in javascript

Tags: javascript

> I have an array of ranges as you can see in the snippet. when user
>   select certain number from dropdown I want to remove that number from
>   the range and return new ranges,
>
> Everything is working as per my expectation but I think, I have over
>   coded and used too many `if else` statements in my code. I was
>   wondering if there is any better way to do it?
>
> If yes please let me know, if Javascript has any methods to make this
>   simple and reduce the amount of code.

```js
var ranges = [
  {start: 1, end: 100},
  {start: 150, end: 300},
  {start: 400, end: 500},
  {start: 550, end: 650},
];


function onSelect(event) {
  let newRange = [];
  let HMID = parseInt(document.getElementById("mySelect").value);
  
  
  for (let range of ranges) {
      
      if ((HMID > range.start) && (HMID < range.end)) {

          newRange.push({start: range.start, end: (HMID - 1)});
          newRange.push({start: (HMID + 1), end: range.end});
      } else if (HMID === range.start) {

          newRange.push({start: (range.start + 1), end: range.end});
      } else if (HMID === range.end) {

          newRange.push({start: range.start, end: (range.end - 1)});
      } else {

          newRange.push(range);
      }
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(newRange));
  
}

function onSelectAdd() {

  let newRange = [];
  let HMID = parseInt(document.getElementById("mySelectAdd").value);
  
  
  for (let i = 0; i < (ranges.length); i++) {

  let start, end;

  if (HMID == (ranges[i].start -1)) {
      start = HMID;
      end = ranges[i].end;

      newRange.push({start: start, end: end});
  } else if (HMID == (ranges[i].end + 1)) {
      start = ranges[i].start;

      if (ranges.length === (i + 1)) {
          end = HMID;
      } else {

          if (HMID == (ranges[i+1].start - 1)) {
              end = ranges[i+1].end;
              i++;

          } else {
              end = ranges[i].end;
          }
      }

      newRange.push({start: start, end: end});

  } else {
      newRange.push({start: ranges[i].start, end: ranges[i].end});
  }

  }
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(newRange));
}
```

```html
<p>Remove item</p>
<select id="mySelect" onchange="onSelect()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="150">150</option>
  <option value="450">450</option>
  <option value="650">650</option>
</select>

<p>Add removed item</p>
<select id="mySelectAdd" onchange="onSelectAdd()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="150">150</option>
  <option value="450">450</option>
  <option value="650">650</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ranges.forEach(range=>{/* etc */})` The code is otherwise ok.